# Creating a horizontal unordered list?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a horizontal list that isn't precisely aligned, exactly like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiK4Z.png (horizontal and scattered)

Here's what I've got so far:

**HTML**

```
<nav>
         <ul id="menu">
             <li><a href="#">Random</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Stand</a></li>
            <li><a href="#>NAN</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tap</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mart</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dom</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav {

    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    left: 290px;
}

nav ul
 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
 underline: none;
 }

nav ul li { display: inline; margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;}
nav ul li a { color: red;  font-size: 14px; text-decoration: none;}
```

As you can see, although the list is horizontal it is not 'unordered'/scattered as in the image. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please define properly what unordered/scattered means.

Comment: Take a look at li:nth child - you should be able to use it to change positioning based on even or odd.  Note this isn't supported by HTML4 browsers.

Comment: why not just have multiple unordered lists ?

Comment: Sure, by scattered/unordered I mean menu items should not be aligned exactly in a straight line side by side like this: item 1  item 2   item 3  Rather, they should be all in a horizontal line but with some items above others and some below. Is that better?

Comment: It sounds like you want to nested <ul> 's

Comment: Hey Quinn, maybe horizontally nested lists is a better way to put it. Any ideas how to? Making multiple ul's doesn't work (try and compare with image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can position the `<li>`-elements manually with `position: relative` and the position properties `top, right, bottom, left`. I have written a little example for you here: https://jsfiddle.net/c5bw1dbe/

I hope this helps!